# Actor-Isolated Class with Different Actor Isolation

Tags: swift

I've got the new beta of Xcode 13 (beta 4 + 5), and now I get this build error:

> Main actor-isolated class 'My Class' has different actor isolation from nonisolated superclass 'My Super Class'

Not sure how to fix this one, I'm not using any actors.

Does anyone know what this means?

I get the error on [this line](https://github.com/heestand-xyz/PixelKit/blob/8f3255813e581dc7bb04ba2ecaaaea1fdb8328a3/Source/PIX/PIXs/Content/Resource/Image/ImagePIX.swift#L28).

Related Apple Forums [post](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/686154).

**Edit:**

I found out that a simple protocol extension, in the app, of a class in the package can cause this:

```
protocol Test {
    var test: String? { get }
}

extension ImagePIX: Test {
    var test: String? { nil }
}
```

Prefixing the protocol with `@MainActor` solves the bug:

```
@MainActor protocol Test { ... }
```

**Edit:**

Fixed in **Xcode 13 RC**

Comment: Are you using the `@MainActor` annotation on your class or is it inheriting from a class that does?

Comment: I answered my own question. I searched your whole repo and found nothing.

Comment: It's related to Swift 5.5's new concurrency model. The Main Actor is something that runs on the main thread in an isolated context. Is this error occurring in an app that is consuming PixelKit or from PixelKit itself?

Comment: You're right, I'm not using @MainActor. I get the error in an app using the package.

Comment: Could you paste some of the code where this package is getting invoked?

Comment: It's very deeply integrated in the app, I don't have a clear entry point.
Tho the package builds fine, so I guess it's something in the app.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the errors. The Classes don't seem to be related to each other. I'm gonna go back in git history...

Comment: Yea, that’s an odd one.

Comment: Can you give instructions for reproducing this issue?

Comment: @matt unfortunately I can't reproduce the issue outside of my app. It works in another app where I have the same package.

Comment: If you mark all the "nonisolated" classes @MainActor does the problem go away?

Comment: I tried marking my superclass with @MainActor, tho that gives me more issues than I originally had.

Comment: Ok, so I found that all the classes that are effected I have extended in my app with a simple protocol. Removing this extension fixes the issue.

Comment: This is very cool. Can we reproduce this using a simple example with two classes and a protocol?

Comment: I could not replicate it with an empty package, tho you can replicate it with PixelKit: https://github.com/heestand-xyz/PixelKit
I could replicate it with a simple empty app with the simple protocol and extension on `ImagePIX`. Tested with tag 2.0.10.

Comment: Going back to Xcode 13 (beta 3) also solves the issue.

Comment: Ran into the same issue with a similar setup, but it's fixed now with Xcode 13 RC / Xcode 13.0 (13A233).